# An exercise in Kunen

Tags: set-theory, forcing

The following exercise appears in Kunen;

In $M$, let $\mathbb{P}=Fn(\kappa,\lambda)$ (i.e. the finite partial functions), where $\aleph_0\leq\kappa<\lambda$. Then $\lambda$ is countable in $M[G]$, and all cardinals of $M$ above $\lambda$ remains cardinals in $M[G]$.

He gives the hint: If $f=\bigcup{G}$, then $f\upharpoonright\omega$ maps $\omega$ onto $\lambda$.

I'm not really sure how you show that. It is certainly true that $f$ is a function from $\kappa$ onto $\lambda$ but I can't really  see why the hint would be true.

Also, how do you do the rest of the problem? In the book, preservation of cardinals is shown via showing the preservation of cofinalities. Here cofinalities are not going to be preserved (If I accept the hint, then ordinals of cofinality $\lambda$ in the ground model will have cofinality $\omega$ in the extension).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $\alpha < \lambda$, consider $D_\alpha := \{p \in Fn(\kappa, \lambda) : (\exists n \in \omega)(p(n) = \alpha)\}$. Since elements of $Fn(\kappa, \lambda)$ are finite partial functions, each $D_\alpha$ is dense. Therefore by the genericity of the generic filter, $f \upharpoonright \omega$ is a surjection of $\omega$ and $\lambda$. $\lambda$ is countable in the generic extension.

Note that in $V$, $|Fn(\kappa, \lambda)| = \lambda$. Therefore, $Fn(\kappa, \lambda)$ has the $\lambda^+$-cc. Hence all cardinals above $\lambda$ are preserved by a general result about chain conditions (this result is in Kunen).

Answer (score 2):

For the hint: Isn't it true that for any $α ∈ λ$ and any $f ∈ Fn(κ, λ)$ can be extended so it maps some $n ∈ ω$ to $α$? Then $\{f ∈ Fn(κ, λ): α ∈ f \upharpoonright ω\}$ is dense.

And about the cardinal preservation, it should be true that cardinals $≥ λ$ are preserved and their regularity is also preserved, but you probably need to assume that $λ$ is regular. You should also observe and use that your $Fn(κ, λ)$ is $λ^+$-cc.

Comment: I'll work on the problem with your suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't $\aleph_\lambda$ in the ground model have cofinality $\lambda$ but cofinality $\omega$ in the extension? Wouldn't this mean regularity is not preserved as well? The preservation of regularities is equivalanet to the preservation of cofonalities above $\lambda$

Comment: Also I'm not sure how to translate your comment on the hint. From your comment you get different functions from $\omega$ that map onto each given $\alpha$. I can't see a good way to put all of these functions together to get a new function from $\omega$ to $\lambda$.

Comment: @DanulG If $\{f ∈ Fn(κ, λ): α ∈ f \upharpoonright ω\}$ is dense then $α ∈ \bigcup G \upharpoonright ω$. Also if you see that $\bigcup G$ maps $κ$ onto $λ$ then you should see this as well since it both holds for the same reason.

Comment: @DanulG About the cofinalities, $\aleph_λ$ has cofinality $λ$ in ground model and $ω$ in extension. But $λ = ω$ in extension, so cofinality is preserved. See Lemma 6.9 on page 213 in Kunen.

Comment: @user87690 I don't think $Fn(\kappa, \lambda)$ is $\kappa$-cc. The set of functions in $Fn(\kappa, \lambda)$ with domain $\{0\}$ is a maximal anti-chain of size $\lambda$.

Comment: @GME: Sorry that's part of $κ$-$λ$ typo I forgot to correct. There should be $λ$-cc. And now I realize that I really mean $λ^+$-cc. Like ccc is not $ω$-cc.