# Counting finite partial functions between infinite sets

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Let $\kappa, \lambda$ be cardinals such that $\lambda > \kappa \geq \omega$.
I'm trying to show that the set of finite partial functions from $\kappa$ to $\lambda$ has cardinality $\lambda$.

It is remarked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/849729/223938) that this is the case, but I can't seem to see why.

Comment: A finite partial function from $\kappa$ to $\lambda$ is a finite subset of $\kappa \times \lambda$.

Comment: *Facepalm* of course! I figured it had to be something obvious like this . @Jonathan if you write this up as an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly there are at least $\lambda$ many such finite partial functions. This gives a bound from below.

But a finite partial function from $\kappa$ to $\lambda$ is also just a finite subset of $\kappa\times\lambda$. Elementary cardinal arithmetic yields $(\kappa\cdot\lambda)^{<\omega} = \lambda^{<\omega} = \lambda$ which gives a bound from above.